# how to calculate location different from distance

Tags: javascript, gis

i am new in gis. I am working in JavaScript.

suppose there is center latlong. another point is target(latlong) in n miters far from center.  how to calculate this location difference(center - latlong) from center and n in miter.

guys please help me.

lets consider earth is properly spherical.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the length of a "straight" line on the surface of a sphere, based on lat/long coordinates of the end points? Are you having trouble with the appropriate mathematical formula, or with just the JavaScript part?

Comment: What code have you written so far? Which part are you getting stuck on? Please add a code snippet to the question that shows where you're having a problem.

Comment: function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var radius = 6371e3; // meters
    var dLon = gis.toRad(lon2 - lon1),
        lat1 = gis.toRad(lat1),
        lat2 = gis.toRad(lat2),
        distance = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) +
            Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon)) * radius;

    return distance;
  }  above javascript function is for calculating distance,                                           function(lat, long, distance){

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add those details, don't post blocks of code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
  function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var radius = 6371e3; // meters
    var dLon = gis.toRad(lon2 - lon1),
        lat1 = gis.toRad(lat1),
        lat2 = gis.toRad(lat2),
        distance = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) +
            Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon)) * radius;
    return distance;
  }
```

above javascript function is for calculating distance,

```
function(lat, long, distance){
  //can i calculate lat_difference, long difference
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to answer your question, or provide clarification of what you are asking? If the latter, please edit your question and add the details there and then delete this answer. Regarding your "can I calculate" comment within the (otherwise) empty function, if you want another lat/long as function *output* you'd need to specify the *direction* as well as the distance.

Comment: Are you pretending in your second function to calculate a new lat long coordinates, giving a lat long center and distance only? If that's the case you need to know the azimuth between the two points.

Answer (score 1):

here is your code:-

```
<script>

Math.radians = function(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};


function calculateDistance(lat,lon,lat_center,lon_center){

var distance = ( 6371 * Math.acos( Math.cos( Math.radians(lat) ) * Math.cos( Math.radians( lat_center ) ) 
                        * Math.cos( Math.radians( lon_center ) - Math.radians(lon) ) + Math.sin( Math.radians(lat) ) * Math.sin(Math.radians(lat_center)) ) )*1000;
console.log(distance+"  meter");
return distance;
}


var lat = '38.898556';
var lon = '-77.037852';

var lat_center = '38.897147';
var lon_center = '-77.043934';

calculateDistance(lat,lon,lat_center,lon_center);//will return 549 meter

//for getting lat and lon from a distance from a given point

//lat1 = latitude of start point in degrees

//long1 = longitude of start point in degrees

//d = distance in KM

//angle = bearing in degrees

function get_gps_distance(lat1,long1,d,angle)
{
    //# Earth Radious in KM
    var R = 6378.14;

    //# Degree to Radian
    var latitude1 = lat1 * (Math.PI/180);
    var longitude1 = long1 * (Math.PI/180);
    brng = angle * (Math.PI/180);

    latitude2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(latitude1)*Math.cos(d/R) + Math.cos(latitude1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng));
    longitude2 = longitude1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(latitude1),Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(latitude1)*Math.sin(latitude2));

   // # back to degrees
    latitude2 = latitude2 * (180/Math.PI);
    longitude2 = longitude2 * (180/Math.PI);

   // # 6 decimal for Leaflet and other system compatibility
   lat2 = latitude2;
   long2 =longitude2;
var tab = {};
   // Push in array and get back
   tab[0] = lat2;
   tab[1] = long2;
   return tab;
 }

 get_gps_distance('38.898556','-77.037852',.549,90);

</script>
```

Comment: according to above example i want to calculate lat , lon with given lat_center, lon_center and distance

Comment: you need direction for that, because there can be many lat long for that distance from a given point.

Comment: YES you are correct. can i get 4 lat lng for 4 direction ??

Comment: @roconmachine i have edited my answer according to your need.let me know if it works

Comment: @roconmachine please accept the answer if its what you need, so that it can help others.